# Reviews on search results

Tags: seo, metadata

Our website collects feedback from all of our customers which is 99% positive.  I have see site have their own reviews listed under there search results.  Please look at image for example.

[image]

I want to know how I can do that for my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called microdata. You want the [rating schema](http://schema.org/Rating).

Comment: Interesting.  I have never heard of http://schema.org.  I take it Google looks at this data.

Comment: Yep, they use it for quite few things.

Answer (score 0):

Its "Google Business" you are searching for, register, create page, and customer will review :)